# Setting affinity within OpenMP parallel region

Tags: c++, openmp

I'm trying to see if it's possible to set affinity within an OpenMP region using pthread_setaffinity_np() call, assuming the underlying implementation uses pthreads for OpenMP workers. In the example code below, the call to set affinity does not return an error and the sched_getcpu() call also confirms that core affinity has been set correctly. However, this way of setting affinity causes considerable performance degradation compared to using GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY environment variable to set affinity, which indicates some underlying issue with the use of pthread_setaffinity_np(). Are there any known issues with using pthread_setaffinity_np() inside OpenMP regions? For my use-case, I need to use pthreads that are 'masters' and each pthread will call its own OpenMP regions and will need to set affinity explicitly for the respective OpenMP regions.

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum) num_threads(num_drones)
  for (int i=start_N;i<end_N;i++){
    if(set[omp_get_thread_num()] == 0) {
      set[omp_get_thread_num()] = 1;
      cpu_set_t cpuset;
      CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);
      CPU_SET(rank*num_drones+omp_get_thread_num(), &cpuset);

      int error = pthread_setaffinity_np(pthread_self(), sizeof(cpuset), &cpuset);
      if (error != 0) {
        cout<< "\nError setting affinity";
        abort();
      }
    } else if (set[omp_get_thread_num()] == 1){
      set[omp_get_thread_num()] = 2;
      assert(rank*num_drones+omp_get_thread_num() == sched_getcpu());
    }
    sum += v1[i];
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a **bad** idea. The OpenMP runtime will almost certainly be optimising its internal algorithms and data structures based on the affinity of the threads which it has established. (E.g. using a hierarchical barrier to minimise cross-cache and cross-socket communication). You are stamping all over that.

You say

> I need to use pthreads that are 'masters' and each pthread will call
> its own OpenMP regions and will need to set affinity explicitly for
> the respective OpenMP regions.

yet you haven't said anything about **why** you believe you need to do this.

This feels very like a classic "I have a problem I'm not going to explain to you, but here's my solution that doesn't work, so please fix that solution for me" question.

If you were to explain your **real** problem we might be able to provide more help...

(In particular, choosing thread affinity sensibly using OpenMP's mechanisms may be all that you need. See [Controlling OpenMP Thread Affinity](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.1/openmpsu41.html#x61-610002.6.2)).